# In Github Actions: Dynamically select the environment value based on Dropdown Choice

Tags: github-actions

In Github Actions unable to select the Environment value based on input dropdown choice.

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with running Fortify scans using ScanCentral into Fortify SSC

name: Namelink Scan

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      choice:
        type: choice
        description: Please select the project to scan
        options:
        - Factorysite
        - HouseSite
env:
    Factorysite: "https://company.com"
    HouseSite: "https://house.com"

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "Scan"
  Scan:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: windows-latest
    environment:
      name: Test
      url: ${{ env.${{ inputs.choice }} }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

Error:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/Namelink.yml (Line: 27, Col: 12): Unexpected symbol: '${{'. Located at position 5 within expression: env.${{ inputs.choice
```

I tried modifying the environment section different ways but nothing worked as mentioned below

```
environment:
      name: Test
      url: ${{env.echo ${{ inputs.choice }}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [format](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#format) expression:

**Example:**

```
url: ${{ format('env.{0}', inputs.choice) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the                                                                        ```url: ${{ format('env.{0}', inputs.choice) }} ```                                                    and getting below warning message                                                      ```Annotations
1 warning
Scan
Environment URL 'env.Factorysite' is not a valid http(s) URL, so it will not be shown as a link in the workflow graph.```

Answer (score 1):

The exact output which I am looking is achieved using contexts as mentioned below.

```yaml
environment:
  name: Test
  url: ${{ env[inputs.choice] }}
```